# is it possible to input a custom logo to the shipping label with shippo?

Tags: api, shippo

When integrating the shippo api and a web app, is there a way to input a custom logo onto the shipping label. If so what carriers can we do this with?

Comment: Can you share code please?

Answer (score 1):

Shippo doesn't support the ability to add a logo directly through the API or Web app.

https://support.goshippo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203723945-Customizing-your-shipping-label

Shippo only supports the ability to add custom text to labels for carriers that support this functionality.